# Json to XSL FO creation using Java

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a JSON which has text and inline styling such as Bold,italics . i have to apply this styling to the text mentioned in json and create an XSL FO file which will be used afterwards to generate a PDF out of it.

JSON :

[input Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOVgH.png)

Output expected :

[image: Output]

Comment: XSLT 3 can process JSON, there are two ways, to use `json-to-xml` to convert the JSON to XML and then process the XML with template rules, or you can also treat JSON as XDM maps/arrays and process these with template rules. Anyway, the rest is normal XSLT processing and creating XSL-FO is a question of knowing and using the XSL-FO elements.

Comment: i want to create xsl fo file which should have xsl fo tags which can be used further to generate the pdf

Comment: Well, what have you tried, where did you get stuck?